# How to display a widget when a OptionMenu's option is chosen?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have an `OptionMenu`, and I want that when one of its options is selected a widget is displayed.

For example

```
...
var = StringVar()

w = OptionMenu(root, var, "apple", "orange", "grapes")
w.grid(column=1, row=1)
w.config(width=15)

var.set(" ")
```

Now, if I select `"apple"`, then it should display a label or a button saying "apples are red".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you're after

```
import tkinter as tk

def toggle(item):
    #Destorys all existing widgets in frame
    for wid in wid_frame.winfo_children():
        wid.destroy()

    #Packs the selected widget
    if item == 'Label':
        tk.Label(wid_frame, text='Hello World!').pack()

    elif item == 'Button':
        tk.Button(wid_frame, text='Hello World!').pack()

    elif item == 'Entry':
        tk.Entry(wid_frame).pack()

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar()
var.set("Pick Widget")

op_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, "None", "Label", "Button", "Entry", command=toggle)
op_menu.pack()
op_menu.config(width=15)

wid_frame = tk.Frame(root)
wid_frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```